# What is the difference between char* s and char *s?

Tags: c, pointers

As per the title. I see certain people declaring a pointer as `char* s`, and others declaring it as `char *s`. Also I see some people doing, say, `s = (char*) malloc(5)` instead of doing `*s = malloc(5)`. Is there a difference between that as well? Apologies if this question is repeated, I understand the concept of pointers, but have great difficulty understanding the syntax used to represent pointers in C.

Comment: No difference at all.

Comment: You do not need the cast for `malloc`

Comment: `*s = malloc(5)` would be wrong, unless `s` is `char**`. And `malloc()` shouldn't be cast since it's not needed.

Comment: So if I do something like `char* s = null;` and `char *t = null;`, `s == t` will return true?

Comment: @WetFeet If you mean `NULL`, instead of `null`, then yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference.

A sort of convention has grown up: folk like to think of `char*` as being the *type* for `s` (which is, of course, a pointer); this can make source code more readable.

But really `char` is the type, and `*s` the variable. You can see this by writing

`char* s, t;`

`s` is a pointer, but `t` is a plain-old `char`. If you wanted both `s` and `t` to be pointers, you'd have to write

`char *s, *t;`

or the obfuscated

`char* s, *t;`

Comment: Hard to believe that this is not a multi-dup.

Comment: I like to think 'char*' as the type, and 's' as the variable name, +1 :D

Comment: @MartinJames: It's a dangerous question to answer (i) possibly a duplicate and (ii) borderline opinion-based.

Comment: Saying that `char` is the type `*s` is the variable isn't really sensible either.  It doesn't make sense for `void *p`, `sizeof (T *)`, etc.  I think it's better to say that `*` binding with the variable name is a quirk of the C grammar rather than trying to rationalize it.